# AttributeError: module 'RPi.GPIO' has no attribute 'ChangeDutyCycle'

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, pwm, pigpio

Starting Day 2 troubleshooting this error.  Code used to work on a previous rasp pi 4B but doesn't on a new one so I'm assuming I'm missing some breaking change.

Problem:

Using `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO` I run some basic setup:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(pin_motor_1_a, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pin_motor_1_b, GPIO.OUT)
motor_1_f = GPIO
```

which runs. When I get to any code that uses the GPIO object it says i'm missing that attribute so:

```
motor_1_f.start(0)
```

Errors:

`AttributeError: module 'RPi.GPIO' has no attribute 'start'`

If I remove the start call I get further down my code and just have the same error on other things like:

`motor_1_f.ChangeDutyCycle(0)`

Gives:

`AttributeError: module 'RPi.GPIO' has no attribute 'ChangeDutyCycle'`

I've wiped my SD card several with Raspberry Pi OS Lite times and went through the python3 / pip3 setup and can't get past this error.  This is my entire setup on first boot:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt install git -y
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
sudo apt install python3-venv -y
sudo apt install python3-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libgpiod2 -y
sudo apt-get install wiringpi -y
sudo apt-get install -y python-smbus -y
sudo apt-get install -y i2c-tools -y
sudo apt-get install raspi-config -y
sudo apt-get install rpi.gpio -y
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools -y
  
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-rplidar
pip3 install pygame
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
pip3 install --upgrade adafruit-python-shell
pip3 install --upgrade adafruit-circuitpython-dotstar adafruit-circuitpython-motor adafruit-circuitpython-bmp280
pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-hcsr04
pip3 install adafruit-blinka
```

What am I missing? - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions are part of GPIO.PWM.

Instead of `motor_1_f = GPIO` try `motor_1_f = GPIO.PWM(channel, frequency)`

Comment: The reason this code worked before is because that's how it was before - I don't know why I changed it :facepalm: